# What can cause "Requesting resource xxx failed because it is complex"

Tags: java, android, android-resources, r.java-file

In my app at the startup I have this error :

```
Requesting resource 0x7f05002b failed because it is complex
```

followed immediately by

```
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(3087): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

In R.java I have for 0x7f05002b

```
public static final class string {
    public static final int common_google_play_services_unknown_issue=0x7f05002b;        
}
```

and in res\values\values.xml I have

```
<string name="common_google_play_services_unknown_issue"><xliff:g id="app_name">%1$s</xliff:g> is having trouble with Google Play services. Please try again.</string>
```

and I have the same in all languages res folders like `/res/values-de/values.xml` or `/res/values-fr/values.xml`

So what can cause the Requesting resource 0x7f05002b failed because it is complex? note: I am under Delphi not under Android Studio and I build myself the r.java with aapt.exe.

**NOTE**

If I delete all languages res folders like `/res/values-de/values.xml` or `/res/values-fr/values.xml` then I don't have the error any more!

Comment: The [r] tag is for the r programming language. Please tag appropriately.

Comment: upps sorry my mistake